# Timefmt for day of the year in gnuplot

Tags: datetime, gnuplot

I am using gnuplot 5.4.4

How can I make the pseudocolumn 0 show the day of the year and properly handle this with xdata time?

A minimal working example that shows the issue:

```
plot filename u 0:1
```

Each line of the file represents a day of the year starting on Jan 1st. Therefore I set the x axis to show time and set the time format specifier to %j (day of the year 1-365) as per the manual.

```
set xdata time; set timefmt "%j"; replot
```

In view of the result (see attached minimal working example figure) it looks like the special column $0 is interpreted as a minute rather than a day of the year. Reformatting the xtics label with

```
   set format x "%j"
```

does not solve the problem (see attached figure).

[image: minimal working example]

[image: Minimal working example with set format x "%j"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an explanation why the following does not give the expected result,

```
reset session
set xdata time
set timefmt "%j"
set format x "%j"
set samples 366

plot '+' u 0:1
```

I'm just speculating that `"%j"` might not work as input format and gnuplot still thinks that input is the default `"%s"`, i.e. seconds since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00 UTC). Hence, in order to get the desired output, multiply the pseudocolumn `$0` with number of seconds per day, i.e. `24*3600`.

```
reset session
set xdata time
set timefmt "%j"
set format x "%j"
set samples 366

plot '+' u ($0*24*3600):1
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

If you handle time in seconds, `0` will be Jan. 1st 1970. So, if the leap year is important for you, you need to convert your pseudocolumn `$0` into your "correct" year, e.g. 2024, by adding an offset `t0 = strptime("%Y",2024")`. Check `help strptime`.

The example below does that. Actually, there, `set xdata time` and `set timefmt "%j"` are not used, but `set format x "%j% timedate"` instead, but then you have to give the xrange in seconds as well using `strptime()`. The second plot is zoomed into end of year 2024 and you can see that there are 366 days.

**Script:**

```
### day of the year for certain year
reset session

# create some test data
set table $Data
    set samples 400
    plot '+' u (cos($0*0.025)) w table
unset table

t(col) = column(col)*24*3600 + strptime("%Y","2024")

set multiplot layout 2,1

    set format x "%j" timedate
    plot $Data u (t(0)):1 w p pt 7 lc "red"

    set xrange[strptime("%Y-%m-%d","2024-12-26"):strptime("%Y-%m-%d","2025-01-04")]
    replot
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It is an nice workaround. It is always safer to operate with seconds. On a second thought day of the year as a variable is troublesome, if only due to leap days. It also puzzles me that in the first example 00:01 looks to me like HH:MM rather than MM:SS.

Comment: @jmmo so, does this solve your issue? Question answered?

Comment: Yes, it was solved with the first answer, and so is more than solved with the enlightening addition. I am more than grateful to you. In my previous replay I forgot to clarify the problem of the leap year. I meant 2024 as an example, and I had already consider counting seconds since 2024-01-01 to circumvent this issue. In the reply I just pointed out that day of the year as an input variable is complicated; therefore it is understandable that my first approach did not work.

Comment: @jmmo good to hear. If it answered your question please accept the answer (and upvote if it was helpful) for not letting the issue/question appearing unsolved.

Comment: I will do that. I usually forgot the Stack nettiquete. I am sorry about that.